# Decrypt a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, encryption

I have a column for storing passwords in a SQL Server database table, where all the data is encrypted like this:

```
25-4B-F1-CB-2C-12-85-EB-17-2E-36-C0-B4-01-2C-28
```

How can I decrypt this data into a readable form? I'm using SQL Server 2012. I need this help badly & your help would be reaally appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You don't. This looks like the result of [hashing a password](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function). I suspect it was hashed using the MD5 function going by the length.

Comment: Any chance I can read the datas?

Comment: No, that's the whole point of hashing. It's a one-way function.

Comment: Is there any way I can use this column in my ASP.Net web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an output of `md5` hash function where each byte is converted to hex string and separated by dashes. Output of md5 is 128 bit and here is exactly 16 bytes of data. `sha-1` and `sha-2` hash functions produces larger outputs so it is unlikely to be that functions.

You can't decrypt it, as by design md5 if non-invertible function.

But if these data are actually some hashed passwords - you are still able to use these passwords to authenticate your users.

All you need - get plain text password from user, compute md5 hash of it using TSQL [HashBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) function, convert it byte-by-byte to your saved format (hex string separated by dashes) and compare to your saved value. Or, of course - you can preliminary transform that saved values back to varbinary and save in another column and compare that varbinaries with output of md5 - it's up to you.

Comment: Ok I'll try. Just to be clear, do I need to do some extra to use these passwords in asp.net website?

Comment: I don't think you need something except built-in TSQL function HashBytes. Of course, assuming your data is really md5 hashes.

Comment: Ok I'll check. Tnx for the info.